# syn flooding attack on a telnet server that listens on multiple ports

Tags: sockets, security, tcp, network-programming, telnet

I want to implement a telnet server which listens on different ports for different applications. How to do it in a clean and efficient way?
Suppose I am able to do it, i.e my telnet server listens on port 23 and 12345. If an attacker launches an SYN flooding attack against the telnet server on my telnet server at port 23. What will happen to another port - 12345, when the attack is successful? Is it still accessible?

Answer (score 0):

A SYN flood attack is fully handled in the OS kernel. A server doing [accept](https://linux.die.net/man/3/accept) will only return from accept if the three-way-handshake to establish the TCP connection was already successful, which is not the case with SYN flooding.

But, SYN flooding will affect the memory usage of the system. If this will only affect the single socket or will affect the system in general depends on the OS and maybe its configuration. But it should not actually matter if there is a process handling multiple sockets vs. multiple processes each handling a single socket.